# Find in jQuery only for first nested tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table id="tab">
    <tr><td>dsf</td><td>dsf</td></tr>
    <tr><td>dsf</td><td>dsf</td></tr>
    <tr><td>dsf</td><td>
        <table id="tab2">
            <tr><td>dsf</td><td>dsf</td></tr>
            <tr><td>dsf</td><td>dsf</td></tr>
        </table>

        </td></tr>
</table>

#tab td {
border: solid 1px red;
}

#tab2 {
background-color: green
}

$("#tab").find("tr").css("background-color", "red");
```

This function find all TR in #tab. i would like find only first TR, not nested TR.

Is possible without add class for TR? i would like make this only with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#tab>tr").css("background-color", "red");
```

that would do what I think you are trying to do XD

Otherwise you could try

```
$("#tab").find("tr:first-child").css("background-color", "red");
```

question was unclear :P

Answer (score 3):

`find` finds all descendant elements.

It sounds like you want `.children('tr')`.

You can also do `$('#tab > tr')`

Comment: Browsers automatically add a `tbody` element so you need to include that: `#tab > tbody > tr`.